# jQuery – on('click') append doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/D6be5/

**HTML**

```
<table class="example" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Enter text</label>
            <textarea>Enter text</textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clone"></tr>
</table>

<p><button id="add-row">Add Row</button></p>​
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function(event) {
        if ( ! $(event.target).closest('table').hasClass('example')) {
            $('table label').show();
            $('table textarea').hide();
        }
    });

    $('table td').on('click', function() {
        $('table label').show();
        $('table textarea').hide();
        $(this).find('label').hide();
        $(this).find('textarea').show();
    });

    $('#add-row').on('click', function() {
        _this = $('table tr.clone')
            .clone()
            .removeClass('clone')
            .insertBefore('.clone');

        _this.append('<td><label>Enter text</label><textarea>Enter text</textarea></td>');
    });                
});​
```

**CSS**

```
table textarea {
    display: none;
}

table .clone {
    display: none;
}​
```

The link above explains what I'm trying to do.

Basically the problem is this. I have a **label** and **textarea** within a **td**, the **textarea** is hidden and only the **labels** show at start. When the user clicks on the cell of the table it hides the **label** and shows the **textarea**, which works fine until you try and add a clone of the row then it doesn't do anything.

**Edit**: Forgot to mention why I'm cloning the row and adding the cells afterwards. In my actual code I allow for column creation as well and I do a count of the rows and add the cells after.

Thank you very much for any help =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another Method.

```
$('table').on('click', "td", function() {

})
```

Comment: Bingo! Works a treat =) .. Strange though why doesn't it work the other way?

Comment: The Jquery official website explains this problem,http://api.jquery.com/on/, and also offer the resolution.

Comment: Should pick one quote style and stick to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the click handler to

```
$(document).on('click', 'table td', function() {
//Your code
}
```

Comment: This binds much larger than it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using the `.on()` method on your `$('table td').click()` event:

```
$('table td').on('click', function() {
    $('table label').show();
    $('table textarea').hide();
    $(this).find('label').hide();
    $(this).find('textarea').show();
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Dude you freakin' ROCK! Haha .. ah damn that's right it's deprecated, are there ways around it?

Answer (score 0):

hope it might help you

```
$('.example').delegate('td', "click", function() {

}
```