# click event of jQuery doesnt work for dynamically generated li

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please have a look at this [**code**](http://ideone.com/R7jKAb) in which every function works perfect but only the click event (which is at last of the code)

```
 $('ul#showUsernames li').on('click', function () {
    selectedUsername = $(this).text();
    if (selectedUsername != chatUsername) {
        chatTitleName.text("Chat between " + chatUsername + " and " + selectedUsername);
    }
 });
```

Here I used `.click` and also `bind('click',function` they too didnt work.

I am using `on` here because I am generating the `li` elements [dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6658774/1577396) through jQuery.

I am not sure whether this matters here or not that I am using SignalR in my project.

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery – on('click') append doesn't seem to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133570/jquery-onclick-append-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use event delegation with `on()`

```
$('#showUsernames').on('click', 'li', function () {
   ...
```

this will work also for dynamically inserted list-items and it will be more performant (since you're attaching a single event handler on your `ul` instead of *n* handlers on the `li` elements.

As a sidenote just use `$('#showUsernames')` instead of `$('ul#showUsernames')` since it's faster (it's like a straight `getElementById`)

Comment: so fast and so correct :) I should have asked this six hours ago here. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('ul#showUsernames').on('click', 'li', function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Jquery Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$('li ul#showUsernames').live('click',function () {
```

can use on also  as live is depricate ( thanks to @Mr_Green )

```
$('ul#showUsernames').on('click', 'li', function () {
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated mentioned in the same jquery live link.

Answer (score 0):

Use `live()`

Example:

```
$(".button").live("click", function() {
});
```

Make sure to call `die()` as well, like this:

```
$(".button").die();
```

die() will prevent your event from firing multiple times. This scenario would occur in case your content is being asynchronously loaded multiple times without a synchronous reload of entire page. This is because the old handlers remain in browsers memory, and they get fired as well (simple explanation).

Hope it helps.

Comment: `live` is deprecated since jQuery 1.7. `On()` should be used instead