# click event attached with dynamically created a tag is not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I am creating some a tag dynamically. Then I am trying to attach click event with them. But those events are not firing.

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    onUploadReady();
});

var onUploadReady = function() {
    $('a[name=add]').on('click', function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('table#multiUpload').append('<tr><td style=\"text-align: center;\"><input type=\"file\" name=\"file\"/></td><td><a href="#" name="remove">Remove</a></td></tr>');
        return false;
    });

    $('a[name=remove]').on('click', function(event){
       event.stopPropagation();
       $(this).parents('tr').eq(0).remove(); 
       return false;
    });
}
```

If I do `$('a[name=remove]').live('click', function(event)` instead of `$('a[name=remove]').on('click', function(event)`, then the event is firing. I read somewhere that usage of `live` is discouraged, and we should use `on`. Also event propagation or bubbling can occur if we use `live`. So how do I solve the issue?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tapas_23571113/uUZ9r/).

Comment: May I know why -1? Is it a wrong question?

Comment: We shud not discourage people by downvoting valid questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14133570/1036917

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like:

```
$("parent_selector").on('click', 'a[name=remove]', function(e){
   //do something
})
```

If `parent_selector` is not known, use `document` instead.

In your example, you can write:

```
$("table#multiUpload").on('click', 'a[name=remove]', function(e){
   //do something
})
```

The syntax you are using is just like `bind`. For dynamically added elements you should use the above syntax. In this we attach the handler to parent which already exists, instead of newly added element. So it will work for all elements added in future.

Comment: The parent `table#multiUpload` is known, so I can call it as: `$('table#multiUpload').on('click', 'a[name=remove]', function (event) {//something});`, right?

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely fine.

Comment: Thanks Arvind, its working, I will accept the answer after 7mins.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[name=remove]', function(e){
...
});
```

Comment: this really helped me, thank you. i was having an issue where Google Analytics would not register my onclick trackEvent call when I changed the attibute with jQuery. Changed my function syntax to the above and it worked. Thanks!